# Android Notifications Issue

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm an android newbie, so please be patient!

Finally, I got my XML result from a simple WCF REST API via GCM wishing to build a simple notification with its payload.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    String message = arg1.getStringExtra("payload");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification note = new Notification();
    note.tickerText=message;
    note.when=System.currentTimeMillis();
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), note);

}
```

I'm hearing my default notification sound but my bar isn't showing anything, **What** I'm missing?

---

**EDIT I**

Note:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I tried **Jeeter** suggestion about building the notification up with the builder, however a MINIMUM API 16 is required which isn't good + my Galaxy note test device is 4.0.4 which is API 15!

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    String Message = arg1.getStringExtra("payload");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(
            new Random().nextInt(),
            new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(Message)
                    .setContentText(Message).build());

}
```

> public Notification build ()
>   Added in API level 16
>   Combine all of the options that have been set and return a new
>   Notification object.

---

**EDIT II**

I tried **A--C** suggestion about using NotificationCompat builder.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    String Message = arg1.getStringExtra("payload");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(
            new Random().nextInt(),
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Message")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setContentText(Message).build());

}
```

No errors but nothing changed, I still hear sound with no appearance, however the message reached the onMessage method.

Comment: you need to build it using the Notification's `Builder`. More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Comment: @Jeeter I tried to build it, but it says that the MINIMUM API must be 16, however my Galaxy Note device is 4.0.4 which it API 15

Comment: That's weird, because when you go to the site above, and set it to api level 11, Notification.Builder is still allowed.

Comment: @Jeeter I post EDIT I about your suggestion, which you could try it yourself to see the error.

Comment: You need `NotificationCompat.Builder` note the different enclosing class.

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim I like your use of edit I,II, etc :) Back on topic: I think you also need to set a **small icon** for the Notification. See [this](http://www.sourcetricks.com/index.php/category/android-status-bar-notifications/) for a source example. Also, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) is the doc for the class, for reference.

Comment: @A--C Thanks, Ops! It was about adding a small icon! when I added it it works! thank you and please add it as an answer :)

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim Posted the answer, you should accept it since it did resolve the issue you had :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android requires a small icon to be set for it to actually show your status bar notification.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification), these are the requirements:

> A Notification object **must** contain the following:
>
> • A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
>
> • A title, set by setContentTitle()
>
> • Detail text, set by setContentText()

Additionally, older platforms (Gingerbread and lower) **require** a `PendingIntent` (referred to as the *content `Intent`* in the documentation) passed for the `Notification` to show. This is a limitation of the platform(s).

Depending on how you show the `Notification`, by not setting a *content `Intent`*, the app will crash and the stack trace will be very clear about the reason why.

Using `NotificationCompat.Builder`, it is easy to set a *content `Intent`*  via [`NotificationCompat.Builder#setContentIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: I am not setting contentIntent() because i don't need it.. I just want to cancel the notification once its clicked. so NotificationCompact won't run on GB?

Comment: @Mitesh I suggest you make another question - my answer to this question doesn't seem related to your issue. Make sure to include any stack traces if the app crashes.

Comment: It's related to the current question. Notification is not appearing on GB, but works in JB. No crash issue. I have included the three main points that you have pointed in the answer.

Comment: @Mitesh I still suggest making a new question, you will need to provide code, which doesn't format well in comments. I use `NotificationCompat.Builder` in my app and it runs fine from 2.2 onwards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371200/notification-doesnt-show-in-ginger-beard-but-works-in-jellybean