# Notification doesn't show in Ginger Bread but works in JellyBean

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to show `notification` but it works perfectly in `Jelly Bean` and in `Ginger Bread` it doesn't work. No errors/issue. I just want to cancel the `notification` once its clicked.

**Minimum Api level is 10.**

Here is the code.

```
    NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);

    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notification.setContentTitle("Alarm");
    notification.setContentText("Wake up!!");

    notification.setVibrate(new long[] { 500 });
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notif = notification.build();

    notifyManager.notify(1, notif);
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this from a Service?

Comment: i am running in `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Suprised it's not crashing then. I tried your code and it does fail with a stack trace. You *need* to supply a PendingIntent - that's the way it works on previous versions. The PendingIntent doesn't have to be an Activity, it could probably point to an empty broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

I have an API level check and do something a bit different for anything less than Jelly Bean:

```
if(jellybeanOrHigher())
{
///Jelly bean 
}
else
{  
    NotificationCompat2.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(this.context)
            ........
}
```

That might get around it for you. It took me quite a while to get notifications setup so this was what worked for me.

Comment: I don't want to launch any activity

Comment: don't then, that's just a snippet of my code, just use NotificationCompat2.Builder